# $|f(z)| ≤ 16$ for $|z| = 4.$ Prove that $|f(3i)| ≤ 9.$

Tags: complex-analysis

(a) Suppose that $f(z)$ is analytic for $1 ≤ |z| ≤ 4.$ Assume that $|f(z)| ≤ 1$ for $|z| = 1$ and $|f(z)| ≤ 16$ for $|z| = 4.$ Prove that $|f(3i)| ≤ 9.$

(b) Prove that there is no non-constant analytic function on the Riemann sphere.

For the first part I want to use maximum modulus but not sure how.  For the second part I am not sure why polynomials are not analytic on the sphere.

thanks for any help.

Comment: Polynomials have a pole at $\infty$ on the Riemann sphere. They are meromorphic.

Comment: Can you find a simple function that has $\lvert f(z)\rvert = 1$ for $\lvert z\rvert = 1$ and $\lvert f(z)\rvert = 16$ for $\lvert z\rvert = 4$ and does not vanish on the annulus?

Comment: Suppose you have an analytic function on the sphere, in particular it continuous on a compact (the sphere is compact), so it is bounded. Then, by Liouville's theorem, its restriction to $\mathbb{C}$ is constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (a), denote the annulus by $A = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \colon 1 \leq |z| \leq 4 \}$ and consider the function $g(z) = f(z)/z^2$, which is analytic in $A$. The given data implies that $\sup_{z \in \partial A} |g(z)| \leq 1$. If $|f(3i)| > 1$, then
$$
\sup_{z \in A} |g(z)| \geq \frac{|f(3i)|}{|(3i)^2|} > \frac{9}{9} = 1,
$$
which contradicts the maximum modulus principle.

For (b), @Crostul had a nice answer in his comment, which I'll repeat for completeness: the Riemann sphere is compact, so continuous function on the Riemann sphere must be bounded. If one then restricts the function to $\mathbb{C}$, Liouville's theorem implies that it must be constant.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Best answer possible!